# No line breaks in auto-generated Text Body from HTML Email

Tags: email, email-template

According to this article:

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000194309&language=en_US

Leaving the text body of an email template blank will cause any edits to that template to be reflected in the text version that is sent out. However, line breaks don't appear to be translating into the text only version in my situation which ends up producing a blob of text all on one line.

Only users whose clients do not accept text email are affected by this, fortunately. Is there a solution for making line breaks work, or is this something that would need to be fixed in a new release?

Comment: Boy, I have seen this myself. I tend to reformat the auto-generated text email template until it displays correctly. Often this means adding extra line breaks.